# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS freezes entirely. what should i do?

Tags: 12.04

Sometimes (like 10 times a day) my ubuntu completely freezes (mouse stop working, the sound who whas playing start a annoying loop "repeating like the last 0.2 seconds") and the only thing im able to do is mannualy restart via the reset button on cpu case. What should i do? is there some system log where i can find the reason? thx and sorry my bad english

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a duplicate of the linked ask. He wants to troubleshoot the problem, not just reboot.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at systems logs located on `/var/log/`, mainly `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`.

This is likely a fault in some hardware component or in some Linux driver module. If that's the case, you should find more information there.

There's a chance that you will only see the driver name, and you have to figure out what device corresponds to. Also, as your system is crashing badly, the logs might not be written on the hard disk on time, so maybe you will find *nothing*.

As this is happening frequently, just leave a terminal opened with the output from this command visible:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

You will probably spot the problem that way.

When I have this kind of problems on desktops I always blame the wifi/networking devices, then the USB devices, then the graphical card, in that order. Then I freak out and run in circles.

If you suspect from some device, e.g. the computer always crashes when downloading a big file, or when playing a video, or when writing on a USB device, you can also try to not using it for a while and see if the system goes more stable. Once you've found the culprit, you can start trying to fix the problem.

Comment: this is what i can see in log after the crash, but i dont know how to understand this: http://pastebin.com/T03VxX9P

Comment: This is no useful information at all. Maybe the crash is before this? Please paste the entire sequence from system start to crash.